# why the cosine similarity never under 0.50?

Tags: word2vec, cosine-similarity

I used cosine similarity to find the similarity of 2 documents. I find the vector of document using word2vec and calculate the vector using cosine similarity to find the similarities, but why the result always above o.5? even when the document not related at all

Comment: I'm confused. your question title is "why the cosine similarity never above 0.50" but then in the body of your question you say that the similarity is **always** above 0.5. Which is it? Always above 0.5, or never above 0.5?

Comment: sorry, its always above 0.5

Comment: maybe there's a lot of a, and, the, then, etc. I don't know anything about this field, just a shot in the dark but I would think even completely unrelated articles might have a lot in common. In the end it's hard to say without looking at your code or your documents.

Comment: I've filtered the stopwords tho

Comment: Given that word2vec only works on individual words, not documents, there's no one way to "find the vector of document using word2vec". Similarly, it's unclear whether you're creating your own word-vectors or using some pre-trained vectors. So you should supply more detail about what you're doing – ideally, actual code. (Generally, cosine-similarities between two vectors will range from -1.0 to 1.0 – but word-vectors will often be a bit lopsided around the origin, so there won't be as many negative-similarities as if they were a random cloud.)